# Who is Mrs Trimmer in Charles Dickens' novel "The Haunted House"?

Tags: history, charles-dickens

Who was Mrs Trimmer in the following excerpt?

> And Prince Arthur, nephew of King John of England, had described himself as tolerably comfortable in the seventh circle, where he was learning to paint on velvet, under the direction of **Mrs. Trimmer** and Mary Queen of Scots.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarah_Trimmer

Comment: How can I be sure?

Comment: Dickens: 7 February 1812 – 9 June 1870; Mrs. Trimmer: 6 January 1741 – 15 December 1810 - I could not find any other Trimmer, and I guess Charles Dickens believed she belonged in Hell :)

Comment: bedankt voor de informatie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it:

Dickens did not like [Mrs. Sarah Trimmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarah_Trimmer)'s protection of young readers from fairy tales

From *Opening The Nursery Door*
 By Mary Hilton, Morag Styles, Victor Watson

[image: Dickens does not like fairy tale reformers]

Comment: so he is teasing her in The Haunted House

Comment: Except she is long dead...

Comment: As noted in your earlier link, Wikipedia suggests that Trimmer also advocated social policy that Dickens might have objected to: *Her writings outlined the benefits of social hierarchy, arguing that each class should remain in its God-given position*.